# Jquery trigger by input instead of button

Tags: jquery, button, click

Html Code :

```
    <input type="text" id="normal_input" />
    <button class="normal_button">Button</button>
```

Js Code :

```
    $('.normal_button').click(function(e){
       console.log(e);
    });
```

The function works good when I click the button 
however when I press enter in the input text, it also trigger the button click function. 
I solved this by change button element to input button 
but I'm still curios about the reason 
is it some kind of jquery bug or something is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default, unless you specify any actions for the `<button>` element, it would act like a `submit` button. Basically `submit` button will get fired when you press enter from its parent form's input control

Answer (score 1):

A button inside of a form by default acts like a submit input. So when you hit enter, it triggers the function.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of a `<button>` is to submit. If you add `type="button"` it will act as a normal button.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bug. Its the default behaviour of a input field on enter. Or on click of a button element with type=submit or a input type=image in a form.

If you wish to avoid submit of your form on press of enter on your input fields. try the code below:

### HTML

```
<form>
<input name="ip" type="text" class="dont_submit" id="normal_input" />
    <input type="button" class="normal_button" value="button"/>
</form>
```

### Script

```
<script>

    $('.dont_submit').keydown(function(ev){
        console.log(ev.which);
        if (ev.which === 13) {            
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    });

</script>
```